# How to enable voice input in Actions on Google console?

Tags: speech-recognition, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, voice-recognition

We are experiencing an inability to issue voice command in the console of Actions on Google, the little microphone button is greyed out there as seen below:

[image]

What does one need to do to enable that capability?

As a reference, when testing with Alexa Skill simulator we were able to give voice commands to invoke Alexa Skills in the same browser:

[image]

I've tried it in both Chrome and Firefox under MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

**IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:**

***Why would an option that works fine in any browser in Alexa Console stop working in Google Console?***

Doesn't seem like a browser misconfiguration to me.

What about Firefox?  Use of the microphone is allowed:

[image]

but the option is still not available:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Tried it on both chrome and firefox with no difference in behavior

Answer (score 1):

Go to the site settings. On Chrome this is available by clicking on the Lock icon in the left-side of the URL bar.

Here you can see site permissions. Make sure that the microphone is set to *Allow*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  What about Firefox? I've added what I'm see in terms of its behavior to the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure where site-level settings for Firefox exist.

Comment: You can try these steps for Firefox: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/204392448-How-do-I-enable-my-mic-in-Firefox-

Comment: @techpeace: Perhaps you didn't understand: what I'm saying is that the feature doesn't work AFTER I've already enabled the permissions (as shown in the print screens attached in the question)

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon In that case, this sounds like a bug. I'd report it to Dialogflow support. It would be helpful to include the output from a tool like https://supportdetails.com/

Comment: @techpeace: Great.  Would it be a Dialogflow bug or an Actions-on-Google bug since I'm testing it via AoG console?  In the "References and How to report bugs" section on their https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java site, they mention that they monitor this SO thread `[actions-on-google]` and provide a link to open a bug, however that link refers back to the same site.  Would you happen to know of other means to open a ticket / speak with Google support?

Comment: It would be an issue with the Actions console.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon You can use the form at the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/